# Use a UITableView as other tableView.talbeHeaderView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nstableheaderview

I use a tableView(named tableViewTwo) as other tableView.talbeHeaderView

The tableViewTwo cant scroll

Why and What can I do

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 12)];
view1.backgroundColor = GL_TABLEVIEW_BACKGROUD_COLOR;

UIView *tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, CGRectGetMaxY(self.lineGroupView.frame))];
tableHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[tableHeaderView addSubview:view1];
[tableHeaderView addSubview:self.candleTopV];
[tableHeaderView addSubview:self.lineGroupView];//it is a tableview
tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView;
```

the code :
github: https://github.com/CoderYLZhang/tableHeaderViewTest

Comment: Perhaps not an answer so I'm not posting as one, but I would STRONGLY encourage you to rethink this. This is not the intended use of a `UITableView` and it will behave unexpectedly (such as the scroll issue). My advice to you would be to utilise table sections and stick the the one table view but add an additional section for the content you want to display in the header table.

Comment: And you expect, that tableview will scrollable ?

Comment: I can make you tableview as your headerview but not scrollable. I will make your whole tableview as headerview

Comment: I hope two can scrollable,and i sent some code to github; the code : github: https://github.com/CoderYLZhang/tableHeaderViewTest  @Jecky

Comment: @CoderYL tabletwo is not scrollable but I can set you whole tableview according your expectations

Comment: @Jecky YES,the tableViewTwo is not scrollable,but other tableView can, i hope both of them can scroll, you have any proposal?

Comment: yes, except tableviewTwo all other tableview are scrollable. I can make you a demo today and let you know @CoderYL